# Invalid hook call. getting error while using material icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm completely new in reactjs.I'm trying to add material icon in my code.But whenever i do that it's giving me error as [ss of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rht0.png)Invalid hook cell

**Navbaar.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import "./navbaar.css"

    import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';

    const Navbaar = () => {
    return (
    <header>
    <nav>
    <div className='left'>
    <div className='navlogo'>
    <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Amazon-Logo-1024x426-1.png?  strip=all&w=960" alt="logo" />

    </div>
    <div className="nav_searchbaar">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" />
    <div className="search_icon">
    <SearchIcon />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
    </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
    )
    }
    export default Navbaar
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any hooks in other files? because the error seems to concern hooks, hooks in React have two rules that you can find in the main react hooks doc which are :

1. Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
   Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.
2. Only Call Hooks from React Functions
   Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.

✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.

By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code.